# Highlighting Flex 3.5 CDATA component in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, syntax-highlighting, cdata

Is there any way to highlight the CDATA component in a .mxml file?
I have Eclipse and Flash Builder 3.5 and the flex components are highlighted, but the CDATA isn't. It contains action script.

Sorry, I meant syntax highlighting. For example:

```
<mx:Canvas ... >
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
  private function foo():void {}
]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by highlight.  Perhaps you should share some code or a sample?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but your Outline View should allow you to click on any script tags to highlight them. Unfortunately you can't give them different ID's, so splitting your code among different blocks doesn't help much.